# Bad print quality on Creality Ender 3

Tags: print-quality, bed-leveling

About 1.5 months ago I changed the springs of my printing bed and since then I have had the same problem again and again. Strangely enough, it only happens sometimes.

I have already realigned the printing bed several times, cleaned it etc. Maybe one of you can tell me what my problem is based on these pictures.

I have also already tried out various underlays.

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]
[image: Image 3]

I print with an Ender 3 , PLA, quality: 0.2 mm, speed: 25 mm/s, initial fan speed: 0 %.

I'm not sure if it helps but on the pictures I tried to print: https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:3495390.

Comment: Your printer nozzle is too far from the bed, it need to be closer. The skirt isn't squished to the plate.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
To level my printer I use a pice of paper and move it between the nozzle and the bed while I move the bed using one of the 4 screws. I stop doing this when I feel the nozzle scratching the paper. Is this the right method to level the bed?

Comment: That is the correct way, but clearly the nozzle it too far away if you look at your printed results.

Comment: Okay I will try readjusting the distance between nozzle and bed. Thanks for you help. Have a nice day.

Comment: No problem, I'll compose an answer!

Comment: This is why I recommend a feller gauge not paper. The nozzle head should be the same distance from the bed as the layer height. This is impossible to achieve with paper. https://www.amazon.com/Hotop-Blades-Feeler-Imperial-Measuring/dp/B06XHXJG31/

Comment: The nozzle should not be a layer away from the bed, paper is more than enough.

Answer (score 1):

From the images you can see that the filament is not squished to the bed, e.g. the extruded skirt looks as if a round rod lies on the bed. The bottom picture shows that the skirt is even dragged (top left); this indicates that the initial bed to nozzle distance is too large. Please decrease the distance or look into your slicer if there is a height offset active.

Comment: I dont found something like height offset in cura. Right now my printer is printing the model sliced with the slicer software made by my printers 
manufacturer. This seems to work.